# CUDA versions confusion

Tags: graphics, version, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'd like to begin learning CUDA but I'm confused about the versions. The latest release of CUDA is 3 and I have the CUDA 3.0.1 driver on my system but in theory my graphics card only supports 1.0. Can I use the features of the later versions or I need to stick to the 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest public release is 3.2 but 4.0 is out in beta to registered developers. Compatibility is based on the features that the hardware supports. You can use the latest version of the SDK but will need to compile for the feature set supported by your card and not attempt to use SDK features that are not supported. You do this by setting the arch flag.

There's some explanation here:

[Fermi Compatibility Guide - NVIDIA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/docs/NVIDIA_FermiCompatibilityGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

CUDA toolkit versions (3.1, 3.2, 4.0) are different from the graphics card compute capability (1.0 / 1.1 for older geforce cards, 1.2 for many mobile cards, 1.3 for slightly old geforce, 2.0+ for the latest fermi architecture). All the toolkits work with all cuda capable graphics cards. Although the complete functionality may not be available, you can still write functional cuda code.